# Can I use json variable replacement from an agent variable in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've got azure devops pipelines that current use json config variable substitution and a deploy to a specific target. Everything there works great.

Now I'm trying to additionally deploy to a second server, but I want that server to replace with a different value for that same variable.

Is there anyway to set a variable on the deployment agent so that one deployment can substitute from environmental variable on the agents, and not specify the hard coded value in the pipeline variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not specify what kind of pipelines and/or agents you are using. I'm assuming you are using self-hosted agents installed to the target servers as you are talking about deployment agent and servers.

I'd suggest that you use variable groups (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group) instead of pipeline variables for server-specific configurations, and then run the config variable substitution with different variable groups on deployments to different servers. Create similar set of variables with environment-specific values to each group.

If you are using classic release definitions, create a stage per server and link the server-specific variable groups to the stages handling deployments to matching servers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#use-a-variable-group). Also consider using deployment groups, and run deployments on server-specific deployment group agents, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).

If you are using yaml pipeline deployment jobs, create a deployment job per server and link variable groups to deployment jobs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-variable-group).